# Odd Echo After foreach loop to add together a string

Tags: php, xml

Hey guys been tearing my hair out for the last half hour cant understand an output im getting, somehow the variable outside the loop gets one value yet inside its working fine can anyone exlpain?

```
private function retrieve_jobs ($xml){
        $i = 0;
        $job_id= "";
                foreach ($xml->result->rowset->row as $row) {
               if($i==10) { break;}
               $job = "".$row['jobID'].",";
               echo $job;

               $job_id = $job_id + $job;
        }
        echo "<hr>";
        echo $job_id;

    }
```

returns

```
    222306493,221469738,221347167,192148888,192148812,192148779,191545019,191544687,191431978,191410960,191404449,191394324,137944351,137241312,135658237,135611078,135586553,86984622,86984602,74752623,74655215,74546907,73206908,73206874,73204769,72540887,72539881,72489215,70936404,70931768,70911740,70907088,70907076,70891956,70702643,70702624,70588927,70424205,70423994,70423605,70399767,70394685,70372461,70372325,70354216,70336955,70236410,70236385,70062221,70055569,70055424,70039478,69734908,69733842,69716985,69716342,69706388,62723392,56140265,55035686,55034424,55020755,54975618,54972666,54961222,
```

(Number Outside Loop)
6396595747    Not sure where this number is coming from it should be the values above.

Comment: Ive tried that method it still doesnt explain the echo under the <hr> giving 6396595747

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use dot `.` as a concatenation operator in php,

```
$job_id = $job_id . $job;
                  ^
```

**Side Note:** The number `6396595747` you getting outside the loop is summation of all the number you getting inside the loop.

Comment: Thanks had no idea it was that simple haha

Answer (score 0):

In `PHP`, `.` is used for concatenation, not `+`.

E.G:

```
$job_id = $job_id . $job;
```

This also works for strings:

```
$str = "Hello";

$str .= ", how are you?";

echo $str; //Hello, how are you?
```

Answer (score 0):

As the other users mentioned in PHP you should use `dot` for string concatenation.

Also in this situation you can use [`implode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function which is much more clear to read instead of concatenating commas each time.

Example:

```
private function retrieve_jobs ($xml){
    $i = 0;
    $job_ids = array();

    foreach ($xml->result->rowset->row as $row) {
       if($i==10) { break;}
       $job_ids[] = $row['jobID'];
       echo $row['jobID'];
    }

    echo "<hr>";
    echo implode(', ', $job_ids);
}
```